# Shell errexit with negated return code

Tags: shell

I have a shell script with errexit option. How can I negate return code of a command inside of the script, so I can expect it to fail?

```
$ cat a
#!/bin/sh
set -o errexit -o xtrace
! true
echo Oook.

$ ./a
+ true
+ echo Oook.
Oook.
```

The `echo` command shouldn't execute.

Comment: Specifically I need to negate `grep -qr` command.

Comment: What do you need to do exactly? Fail when `grep` finds your contents?

Comment: Yeah. A simple lint check of another app's source code.

Comment: Instead of `! true` you could use `true || false`, and this will cause an exit if the first command returns success.  And of course, simple `true && exit` works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell you can't.

From the [spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set).

> -e
>   When this option is on, when any command fails (for any of the reasons listed in Consequences of Shell Errors or by returning an exit status greater than zero), the shell immediately shall exit with the following exceptions:
>   The failure of any individual command in a multi-command pipeline shall not cause the shell to exit. Only the failure of the pipeline itself shall be considered.
>
> The -e setting shall be ignored when executing the compound list following the while, until, if, or elif reserved word, **a pipeline beginning with the ! reserved word**, or any command of an AND-OR list other than the last.
>
> If the exit status of a compound command other than a subshell command was the result of a failure while -e was being ignored, then -e shall not apply to this command.
>
> This requirement applies to the shell environment and each subshell environment separately. For example, in:
>
> ```
> set -e; (false; echo one) | cat; echo two
> ```
>
> the false command causes the subshell to exit without executing echo one; however, echo two is executed because the exit status of the pipeline (false; echo one) | cat is zero.

This is one of the many reasons people often suggest not using `errexit`. It just isn't reliable enough and is too easily "breakable".

As lars indicates in a comment the workaround for this is to either use

```
maybe-true || false
```

or

```
maybe-true && exit
```

Comment: I have solved it by wrapping the command into a subshell. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply investigate `grep`'s exit status, which is 0 when a match was found, 1 if no match found and 2 if an error occurred, and turn the exit status to whatever suits your needs:

```
grep -q "$regex" file
stat=$?
case $stat in
  (0) echo found; exit 1;;
  (1) echo not found; exit 0;;
  (2) echo error; exit 2;;
  (*) echo something unexpected; exit $stat;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by wrapping the command into a subshell.

```
$ cat a
#!/bin/sh
set -o errexit -o xtrace
(! true)
echo Oook.

$ ./a
+ true
```